# Replacing Nones in a python array with zeroes

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, nonetype, map-function

I've just joined two arrays of unequal length together with the command:

```
allorders = map(None,todayorders, lastyearorders)
```

where "none" is given where today orders fails to have a value (as the todayorders array is not as long).

However, when I try to pass the allorders array into a matplotlib bar chart:

```
 p10= plt.bar(ind, allorders[9],   width, color='#0000DD', bottom=allorders[8])
```

..I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

So, is there a way for matplotlib to accept none datatypes? if not, how do I replace the 'Nones' with zeroes in my allorders array?

If you can, as I am a Python newbie (coming over from the R community), please provide detailed code from start to finish that I can use/test.

Comment: To clarify: do you want to replace _all_ `None`s with zeroes, or just the ones that got added to the end of `todayorders` because it's shorter?

Comment: Now that I understand the question better, do not use `map` (or `zip` or `izip_longest` or any other non-`numpy` function that deals with `list`s and/or general iterables) with `numpy.array` objects if you can ever avoid it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
allorders = [i if i[0] is not None else (0, i[1]) for i in allorders]
```

Comment: @abarnert: your generator won't work, as it's `map()` that is adding the `None` values to the output, not that `todayorders` contains any `None` values itself.

Comment: This is a fine answer to the question as stated, but it's not actually very good for what the OP actually wants, which is effectively to stack two `numpy.array` objects of different shapes. Turning them into lists, zipping the lists, and converting back will work, but it's a bad idea. (And the same was true for my answer, until I rewrote most of it…)

Answer (score 8):

With numpy:

```
import numpy as np
allorders = np.array(allorders)
```

This creates an arrray of objects due to the Nones. We can replace them with zeros:

```
allorders[allorders == None] = 0
```

Then convert the array to the proper type:

```
allorders.astype(int)
```

Answer (score 4):

Since it sounds like you want this all to be in `numpy`, the direct answer to your question is really just an aside, and the *right* answer doesn't being until the "Of course…" paragraph.

If you think about it, you're using `map` with a `None` first parameter as a `zip_longest`, because Python doesn't have a `zip_longest`. But it *does* have one, in `itertools`—and it allows you to specify a custom `fillvalue`. So, you can do this all in one step with [`izip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> todayorders = [1, 2]
>>> lastyearorders = [1, 2, 3]
>>> allorders = itertools.izip_longest(todayorders, lastyearorders, fillvalue=0)
>>> list(allorders)
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (0, 3)]
```

This only fills in `0` for the `None`s that show up as extra values for the shorter list; if you want to replace *every* `None` with a `0`, you have to do it Martijn Pieters's way. But I think this is what you want.

Also, note that `list(allorders)` at the end: `izip_longest`, like most things in `itertools`, returns an iterator, not a `list`. Or, in terms you might be more familiar with, it returns a "lazy" sequence rather than a "strict" one. If you're just going to iterate over the result, that's actually better, but if you need to use it with some function that requires a `list` (like printing it out in human-readable form—or accessing `allorders[9]`, as in your example), you need to explicitly convert it first.

If you actually want a `numpy.array` rather than a `list`, you can get there directly, without going through a `list` first. (If all you're ever going to do with it is `matplotlib` it, you probably *do* want an `array`.) The clearest way is to just use `np.fromiter(allorders)` instead of `list(allorders)`. You might want to pass an explicit `dtype=int` (or whatever's appropriate). And, if you know the size (which you do—it's `max(len(todayorders), len(lastyearorders))`), in some cases it's faster or simpler to pass an explicit `count` as well.

Of course if any of the `numpy` stuff sounds appealing, you probably should stay within `numpy` in the first place, instead of using `map` or `izip_longest`:

```
>>> todayorders.resize(lastyearorders.shape)
>>> allorders = np.vstack(todayorders, lastyearorders).transpose()
```

Unfortunately, that mutates `todayorders`, and as far as I know, the equivalent immutable function `numpy.resize` doesn't give you any way to "zero-extend", but instead repeats the values. Hopefully I'm wrong and someone will suggest the easy way, but otherwise, you have to do it explicitly:

```
>>> extrazeros = np.zeros(len(lastyearorders) - len(todayorders), dtype=int)
>>> allorders = np.vstack(np.concatenate((todayorders, extrazeros)), lastyearorders)
>>> allorders = allorders.transpose()
array([[ 1,  1],
       [ 2,  2],
       [ 0,  3]])
```

Of course if you do a lot of that, I'd write a `zeroextend` function that takes a pair of arrays and extends one to match the other (or, if you're not just dealing with 1D, extends the shorter one on each axis to make the other).

At any rate, aside from being faster and using less temporary memory than using `map`, `izip_longest`, etc., this also means that you end up with a final array with the right `dtype` (`int` rather than `object`)—which means your result also uses less long-term memory, and everything you do from then on will also be faster and use less temporary memory.

For completeness: It *is* possible to have `pyplot` handle `None` values, but I don't think it's what you want. For example, you can pass it a `Transform` object whose `transform` method converts `None` to `0`. But this will be effectively the same as Martijn Pieters's answer but much more verbose, and there's no advantage at all unless you need to plot tons of such arrays.

Comment: Thanks -- however, how do I convert the iterator allorders back to an array?  If i pass matplotlib allorders in its current form, I get: TypeError: 'itertools.izip_longest' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: @user1784454: If you want to get it back into a `list` as it was originally, read the paragraph beginning "Also, note that…", which explains exactly what you're asking. If you want to convert it into a numpy `array` instead (which you might want to), see [`fromiter`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html#numpy.fromiter).

Comment: Cool -- yes, I need it to be a numpy array -- I'll look at fromiter.

Comment: @user1784454: In that case, see my updated answer. It's usually a bad idea to step outside of `numpy` (especially to a `list`, but also to an iterator) and then back, if you can do what you want from within `numpy`. So, use something like `vstack` rather than `map` or `izip_longest`.